# How to append new values to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a search box and associated suggestion box to show the suggestions.

Once user type something in the search box, the suggestions will appear. User is able to select one of the suggestions to be added to the search input box. Then user will be able to type other term to receive the suggestions and so on.

I can show the suggestions and find out which suggestion has been chosen but I cant add the selected one to the search box.

I used all the following codes but it shows the alert message but does not change the search box value.

1. `document.getElementById("searchForm").elements[1].value = "0000";`
2. `$("form#searchForm:input").empty();`
3. `$("input[name=term]").empty();`
4. `$('#term').empty()`

**code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectS(value){
        alert("clicked:" + value);
        $('#term').empty()
    }
....

<s:form id="searchForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <s:textfield id="term" name="term" label="Search" onkeyup="find(this.value)"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: can u explain clearly

Comment: What do you mean by "then user can add new search terms next to the selected one."

Comment: You are asking how to set the value of a textbox with a string using concatenation?

Comment: Do you need something like http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple.html ?

Comment: he is saying he can able to show suggestions

Comment: `<s:textfield` ?!  is a **html** tag?

Comment: index in `elements[1]` may be your problem.

Comment: @PSR question is updated

Comment: i think he is using struts.so <s:textfield

Comment: @asifsid88 question is updated

Comment: what is searchbox here

Comment: whats the negative vote for ? if it is unclear ask me to explain more, I need to find an answer, so I will follow it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of JQuery empty(), you should use val() to get/set the *value* of an input.

```
$('#term').val('');    // clears it
```

Or, to append to it:

```
function selectS (value){
    alert("clicked:" + value);
    var curr = $('#term').val();
    if (curr)                      // delimit values nicely, if curr not empty.
        curr += ", ";
    $('#term').val( curr + value);
 }
```